# Website for Datasets - Miles and Shevlin book, "Applying Regression & Correlation"

Tags: dataset, data, linear-regression

I've very much enjoyed Miles and Shevlin (2015) book, "Applying regression & correlation : a guide for students and researchers." The book mentions availability of datasets, but the website provided in the book no longer exists (http://jeremymiles.co.uk/regressionbook). Is there another website that I can find the aforementioned datasets?

Comment: Perhaps you could mention the URL of the website that no longer exists.  Sometimes, URL patterns may change and someone may know how to get to the website. Also, you won't get folks pointing you to the same website because they don't know it is no longer available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That page is archived at https://web.archive.org/web/20161024210121/http://www.jeremymiles.co.uk/regressionbook/ , which will take you to https://web.archive.org/web/20160412090429/http://www.jeremymiles.co.uk/regressionbook/data/index.html .
Some of the datasets are available there; I imagine that some others were not crawled. Certainly I successfully obtained data1_1.xls from there. Do feel free to contribute to Internet Archive if you found their service useful.